# SQL Server Report Server blank screen - first time using it

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I installed SQL Server 2014 Developer edition a few days ago. I am eager to work with SSRS, but I cannot seem get the web based Report Server to work.

Following instructions based on issues from others, I made some system corrections on my Windows 7 Professional system by adding my local machine trusted sites (http : / /minint-teerupj ) - my PC Name.

I proceed to run Internet Explorer as Adminstrator, and go to my report server url:

```
http://minint-teerupj/ReportServer
```

When I do this, all the screen displays is  the following:

```
minint-teerupj/ReportServer - /

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 12.0.2000.8
```

Has anyone has this issue?

Comment: Possibly no report is deployed there...

Comment: zhong you are correct - I deployed a report and now their is a directory listing to browse to it.
However, I still do not see any other configurations options such as  report folder, such as users, folders, report builder, subscriptions, etc...

Comment: There are two URLs there. Open your reporting service configuration manager, and you could find them: webservice URL & Report manager URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I could paste my answers here.

```
There are two URLs there. Open your reporting service configuration manager, and you could find them: webservice URL & Report manager URL.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was accessing the incorrect URL, 
- the report manager url is:

```
http://localhost/reports
```

Thank you zhongxiao